# Overload std::string operator+ for printing enum name

Tags: c++

I have an enum

```
    enum ft_dev_type
    {
        SPI_I2C,
        GPIO
    };
```

I would like to be able to construct a string like this

```
std::string s = "enum =" + SPI_I2C; //would contain "enum = SPI_I2C"
```

To do so, I'm trying to overload the + operator

```
    std::string operator+(const ft_dev_type type) const
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case SPI_I2C: return std::string("SPI_I2C");
            case GPIO: return std::string("GPIO");
        }
    }
```

But I get

> Adding 'ft_dev_type' to a string does not append to the string.

How can I overload the + operator properly?

[edit] below is the class

```
class driver_FT4222
{

public:
    driver_FT4222() {}

    enum ft_dev_type
    {
        SPI_I2C,
        GPIO
    };

    std::string operator+(const ft_dev_type type) const //this line is probably wrong
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case SPI_I2C: return std::string("SPI_I2C");
            case GPIO: return std::string("GPIO");
        }
    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        ...
        std::string s = "enum =" + SPI_I2C; //would contain "enum = SPI_I2C"
        std::cout <<s;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `operator+` appears to be a member function. What class does it belong to?

Comment: Look half a scroll down [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) page to see the valid operator overload forms for member and non-member functions.

Comment: @cigien the same class where the enum is declared

Comment: Then you need to show that code. You appear to have earned enough rep to know that by now :)

Comment: @cigien done :)

Comment: @Victor But neither of the arguments is one of those classes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want the free function:

```
std::string operator+(const char* s, const ft_dev_type type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case SPI_I2C: return s + std::string("SPI_I2C");
        case GPIO: return s + std::string("GPIO");
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid enum value");
}
```

(and similar for `std::string`...)

but better IMO to have a `to_string`

```
std::string to_string(const ft_dev_type type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case SPI_I2C: return std::string("SPI_I2C");
        case GPIO: return std::string("GPIO");
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid enum value");
}
```

to have

```
std::string s = "enum =" + to_string(SPI_I2C);
```